# How do you read the radar in multiplayer?

Tags: titanfall-2

I can't seem to make any correlation between the radar screen and where allies/enemies are in multiplayer modes in Titanfall 2.

There are various shapes that can appear on the radar, like arrows, triangles, and diamonds. What do these mean?

A whole 1/8th of the circle can be colored in the enemy color (orange). What does this mean?

Sometimes, a faded orange circle will appear around a section of the map, which may or may not have anything to do with map objectives. What's this for?

Lastly, sometimes the outer ring of the radar has solid colored in orange sections. What do these indicate?

Are there any other indicators on the radar that I have forgotten about or haven't seen yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### **For Shapes:**

- **Large orange circle:**  An enemy pilot
- **Small orange circle:** Enemy AI controlled entity (other than titan)
- **Orange arrow:** An enemy titan

---

### **The rest of your questions:**

> A whole 1/8th of the circle can be colored in the enemy color (orange). What does this mean?

This is if there are shots being fired within a near area by an enemy.

> Sometimes, a faded orange circle will appear around a section of the map, which may or may not have anything to do with map objectives. What's this for?

In my experience this is where enemy spawns are happening for the current time. The enemy can see this too. Played a game of Pilot vs Pilot last night and the enemies only showed up there.

> Lastly, sometimes the outer ring of the radar has solid colored in orange sections. What do these indicate?

This is similar to the shots being fired but further away from your current location.

> Are there any other indicators on the radar that I have forgotten about or haven't seen yet?

I'm not sure what you mean by diamonds. So I haven't answered that. Other than that I think you got them all.

Comment: This may be grounds for a completely separate question, but do you know the requirements that an enemy actually be marked on the map at a specific location vs. simply showing what octant they're in?

Comment: Not fully sure but my assumption from playing is that they are revealed via maphack/sonar.

Answer (score 1):

Weapon fire is the only way that any enemy shows up on radar. Your allies will always show up on the radar.

When weapon fire is very close to you it will show as a red circle around the center of the map, when it is slightly away from you it will show as a quadrant. 
This is true for all weapons except silenced weapons (such as the mod for the fully auto hand pistol).

Once the weapon fire is revealed, then the associated symbol will show up on the map where the weapon fire took place (or nowhere if it is too far from your radar). Pilots are large red dots, AI are small red dots, and titans are red arrows.

Without weapon fire, a pilot, titan, or enemy AI will *not* show on the radar. Be careful. Clear your lines of sight. Move methodically.